# How to change the script to load the page content only without images etc.?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I have the following greasemonkey script currently:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test_script
// @namespace   my.example.com
// @include     http://example.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(window, undefined) {

        // normalized window
        var w;
        if (unsafeWindow != "undefined"){
                w = unsafeWindow
        } else {
                w = window;
        }

        // You can inject almost any javascript library here.
        // Just pass the w as the window reference,
        // e.g. jquery.min.js embedding:
        // (function(a,b){function ci(a) ... a.jQuery=a.$=d})(w);

        // do not run in frames
        if (w.self != w.top){
                return;
        }
        // additional url check.
        // Google Chrome do not treat @match as intended sometimes.
        if (/http:\/\/example.com\//.test(w.location.href)){
                var link = $('span.link').text();
                if (link) {
                    location.replace(link);
                }
        }
})(window);
```

Once I open `example.com` page, it looks for the URL here and redirects me. It works well, but redirection happens only when all images, style sheets etc. are loaded. How should I fix that? [Looks like](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded) it should happen before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've *shown*, ***will*** fire before images are loaded, but not necessarily before CSS.
**From [Mozilla's DOMContentLoaded doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29)** (and v[erified in Gecko, Webkit and IE](http://molily.de/weblog/domcontentloaded#external-scripts)):

> Stylesheet loads block script execution, so if you have a `<script>` after a `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>`, the page will not finish parsing - and **DOMContentLoaded will not fire - until the stylesheet is loaded.**

Obviously, if the CSS and/or images are small or cached, they might also appear to load before the script fires.

You *might* be able to work around this using [`@run-at document-start`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at). See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660023/331508), and similar, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, but if I add `@run-at document-start` it stops working.

Comment: In your case it's not as simple as *just* adding `@run-at document-start`.  You would also need to wait for the DOM and then use `MutationObserver` to watch for `span.link` to show up.  That gets complicated and seemed beyond the scope of this question.  (The posted code *would* run before images, if not necessarily CSS. And the posted code is pretty "hinky" for just a Firefox Greasemonkey script.)